ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2024-02-12 170000892" SQL state: 22008
I have the below query:
INSERT INTO TEMP_USAGE_REPORTING
  (SELECT ABC.EPCCLASS_ID, ABC.EPCCLASS_SEARCH_PAT, ABC.SERIAL, ABC.EVENT_RECORD_DT, ABC.EVENT_RECORD_TM
   FROM
     (SELECT EVENT_EPC.EPCCLASS_ID, EPCCLASS.EPCCLASS_HEADER, EPCCLASS.EPCCLASS_SEARCH_PAT, EVENT_EPC.EVENT_EPC_URI_SN AS SERIAL, EVENT.EVENT_EVENT_DT, EVENT.EVENT_RECORD_DT, EVENT.EVENT_RECORD_TM, EVENT.EVENT_SUB_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EVENT_EPC.EVENT_EPC_URI_SN, EPCCLASS.EPCCLASS_SEARCH_PAT
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ORDER BY EVENT.EVENT_RECORD_DT) AS RN
      FROM EVENT
      LEFT JOIN EVENT_EPC ON EVENT.EVENT_SUB_ID = EVENT_EPC.EVENT_SUB_ID
      LEFT JOIN EPCCLASS ON EVENT_EPC.EPCCLASS_ID = EPCCLASS.EPCCLASS_ID
      WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(EVENT.EVENT_RECORD_DT::TEXT || ' ' || LPAD(EVENT.EVENT_RECORD_TM::TEXT, 9, '0'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24MISSFFF') >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-02-12'::varchar || ' ' || '170000892'::varchar, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24MISSFFF')
        AND TO_TIMESTAMP(EVENT.EVENT_RECORD_DT::TEXT || ' ' || LPAD(EVENT.EVENT_RECORD_TM::TEXT, 9, '0'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24MISSFFF') <= TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-03-01'::varchar || ' ' || '005959999'::varchar, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24MISSFFF') ) ABC
   WHERE ABC.RN = 1
   GROUP BY ABC.EPCCLASS_ID, ABC.EPCCLASS_SEARCH_PAT, ABC.SERIAL, ABC.EVENT_RECORD_DT, ABC.EVENT_RECORD_TM);

This query is working fine in Oracle but getting this error in Postgres:

ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "2024-02-12 170000892" SQL state: 22008

The time is in "HHmmssSSS" format. For Oracle this condition is working but dont know why it's not working for Postgres. Please if anyone could help with this?
I have tried changing the format to HH24MISSFF3 but this is also not working.

select to_timestamp('2024-02-12 170000892', 'YY-MM-DD HH24missus'); 2024-02-12 17:00:00.892-08 Read Data formatting functions.

A WHERE condition like this can most likely not use an index for searching, unless you made a special index on EVENT.EVENT_RECORD_DT. Storing a timestamp as a timestamp would be easier, faster and less error prone.

Why do you need to convert a char or varchar to timestamp? It would be simpler if you can just use timestamp (without or preferably with time zone) everywhere in your database and SQL.

Why the simpledateformat tag? SimpleDateFormat was a (rather hopeless) Java class that we used up to Java 1.7 at the latest and that we should have forgot everything about by now (substituted by DateTimeFormatterfrom java.time).
